# JButton on JDialog has to be focused to respond to mouse click

Tags: java, swing

[image: Target dialog]

```
public class Mdiag extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public JButton btnClose,ok ;
        public JLabel lblImgErr = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("err.png"));
        public JLabel title = new JLabel(), message = new JLabel();
        private static Mdiag mInstance;

        public Mdiag(JFrame parent, String title,String message) {
            super(parent, true);
            setUndecorated(true);

            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(444, 155));
            setBounds(((int) getToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() - 444) / 2,
                    ((int) getToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() - 155) / 2,
                    444, 155);

            JPanel mainDgPanel = new JPanel();
            mainDgPanel
                    .setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(255, 255, 255), 3, true));
            mainDgPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 444, 155);
            getContentPane().add(mainDgPanel);
            mainDgPanel.setLayout(null);
            mainDgPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#C7AA5"));

            //add Title
            JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel(title);
            lblTitle.setBounds(190, 0, 80, 25);
            panel.add(lblTitle);

            //add Message
            JTextArea txtrTextarea = new JTextArea(message);
            txtrTextarea.setRows(2);
            txtrTextarea.setBounds(76, 62, 336, 80);
            txtrTextarea.setFont(new Font("Iskoola Pota", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            txtrTextarea.setEditable(false);
            txtrTextarea.setFocusable(false);
            txtrTextarea.setOpaque(false);
            txtrTextarea.setBorder(null);
            txtrTextarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            txtrTextarea.setLineWrap(true);
            txtrTextarea.setForeground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
            mainDgPanel.add(txtrTextarea);

            //add ok button
            JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();
            panelButtons.setBounds(43, 115, 336, 30);
            panelButtons.setBackground(Color.decode("#C7AA5"));
            panelButtons.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
            mainDgPanel.add(panelButtons);
            JLabel lblNewLabel = lblImgErr;
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 62, 45, 43);
            mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);
            ok=new JButton("OK");
            panelButtons.add(ok);

            ok.addActionListener(this);

            //add close button
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBounds(1, 1, 440, 27);
            mainDgPanel.add(panel);
            panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panel.setLayout(null);
            btnClose=new JButton(new ImageIcon("close.gif"));
            btnClose.setBounds(406, 0, 39, 25);
            panel.add(btnClose);

            btnClose.addActionListener(this);

            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source == ok || source == btnClose) {
                this.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

In this customized `JDialog`, `close` button is active/focused by default and I can switch to `OK` button using `Tab`.
At any moment if the buton is active then I can click it either using the space bar or the mouse, **but if the button is not active, I can not click it by the mouse, it does not respond**, I have to make it active first, and this is what I do not understand.

Thank you.

Comment: what we are missing is the rest of the code

Comment: What I can see is a mouse listener that doesn't do anything in any of the events, and is not connected to anything. This takes up most of the code you wrote. Then, there is your problem description, but it's not clear. You can tab and space and use the mouse. So what do you need?

Comment: Don't use a MouseListener on a button. Instead you should be adding an `ActionListener` to the button.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you all, I have tried to make the description clear, and added most of the code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I can use the mouse only after selecting the button using Tab!

Comment: Question: why are you creating your own version of a dialog box? Why aren't you using the pre-existing ones that Java supplies? You can have icon, button, and text in a standard dialog box.

Comment: @RealSkeptic JOptionPane looks so raw, and weird if used in a rich application, you can not change its background or the combination of buttons or their text or icons or style!